# How does Wordpress resolve permalinks internally?

Tags: pluggable

I am doing some deep modding of the rewrite system and custom post_types but before I can continue I must find out how WordPress handles the rewrites.

I found the function url_to_postid() but WordPress it self doesn't seam to use it to resolve permalinks into queries?

For example: If I hook into the pre_get_post functions, and browse a page or a custom post_type the provided query now include "is_page" or "attachment" etc  but if i where to type a URL at random, this data will not show. Where does WordPress figure out if the URL is a page|posttype|attachment or not? And how can I hook into this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a look at the [Action Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference#Actions_Run_During_a_Typical_Request), you'll see all of the actions executed before `pre_get_posts`. The two you'll probably want to investigate are [`parse_request`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/parse_request) and [`parse_query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/parse_query) (yes, those are lacking in documentation).

The part you're probably most interested in is `parse_request`, where rewrite rules are matched against the requested URI. You can [see it in source here](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8/src/wp-includes/class-wp.php#L120).

When a front end request happens, the file `wp-blog-header.php` is loaded, which calls [`wp()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8/src/wp-includes/functions.php#L806), which calls the [`main()` method of the `WP` class](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8/src/wp-includes/class-wp.php#L601), which calls the [`parse_request()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8/src/wp-includes/class-wp.php#L120) method. At the bottom of that function, you'll [see where the `parse_request` action is executed](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8/src/wp-includes/class-wp.php#L333).

**EDIT**

Also see this page in Codex for some more in-depth info: [Query Overview](http://codex.wordpress.org/Query_Overview)